# Ubuntu 22.04 - VPN's DNS server not used for resolving addresses

Tags: networking, dns, vpn

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and I've been trying to make VPN connection work next to my normal network. I'd like to route traffic through VPN only for its network (selected "Use this connection only for resources on its network").

I also added manually DNS using `resolvectl`:

```
sudo resolvectl dns tun0 10.10.10.10
```

After this, `resolvectl` prints:

```
$ resolvectl
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp2s0f0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1 fe80::267f:20ff:fe5b:bde9%21981
        DNS Domain: home

Link 3 (wlp3s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (enx00e04c6800a3)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 8 (tun0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 10.10.10.10
       DNS Servers: 10.10.10.10
```

So it seems DNS servers are set properly (192.168.1.1 for enp2s0f0 and 10.10.10.10 for tun0).

Public domains that can be resolved by 192.168.1.1 are getting resolved just fine.
Unfortunately, domains which should be resolved by 10.10.10.10 are not getting resolved.

For example, when trying to resolve `internal.int` using `dig`:

```
$ dig internal.int

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu <<>> internal.int
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55035
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;internal.int.          IN  A

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sun Jul 03 21:53:23 CEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40
```

But on the other hand, when specifying 10.10.10.10 as DNS server, it resolves fine:

```
$ dig internal.int @10.10.10.10

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu <<>> internal.int @10.10.10.10
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47904
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 987649b09c83e7c9763943a462c1f3f6e8bdcf9b730a1234 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;internal.int.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
internal.int.       3600    IN  A   10.2.97.6
internal.int.       3600    IN  A   10.2.97.7

;; Query time: 28 msec
;; SERVER: 10.10.10.10#53(10.10.10.10) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sun Jul 03 21:54:30 CEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100
```

So the VPN in general is working fine (routing is fine, because I can reach 10.10.10.10), resolving public domains is working fine as well (e.g. google.com), but it seems systemd-resolved (or maybe something else?) does not take into account 10.10.10.10 as DNS.

My understanding is that it should look for internal.int using 192.168.1.1 as DNS and if it fails, try resolving the address using 10.10.10.10. Instead, when 192.168.1.1 cannot resolve, it just returns no address.

Is it possible to make systemd-resolved use both 192.168.1.1 and 10.10.10.10 DNS servers?

P.S. I tried setting 10.10.10.10 as secondary DNS server for `enp2s0f0`, next to 192.168.1.1 - it didn't help.

Answer (score 9):

What I had to do was basically:

```
sudo resolvectl dns tun0 10.10.10.10
sudo resolvectl domain tun0 ~.
```

But it has to be run after every time I connected to VPN. To make this settings persistent I needed to do:

1. Mark "Use this connection only for resources on its network" (IPv4 and IPv6 tabs).
2. Disable Automatic DNS and set 10.10.10.10 as DNS in IPv4 tab.
3. Run `nmcli connection modify <VPN-connection-name> ipv4.dns-search ~.`
4. Verify `resolvectl` shows correct DNS server and domain for `tun0` (or similar) link:

```
$ resolvectl
[...]
Link 21 (tun0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 10.10.10.10
       DNS Servers: 10.10.10.10
        DNS Domain: ~.
```